# Skipping row in CSV and inserting in Sqlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, csv

I have a CSV file in below format:
[image: CSV data]

The first row is empty and then Access points data comes after that another empty row comes from where clients data come.
I'm trying to insert this data in two tables of sqlite db but not getting success.

```py
import sqlite3
import csv

con = sqlite3.connect("access_wifi.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS access_points (BSSID TEXT, First_seen TEXT, Last_seen TEXT, Channel INT, 
Speed INT, Privacy TEXT, Cipher TEXT, Authentication TEXT, Power INT, beacons INT, IV INT, LAN_IP TEXT, ID_length INT, 
ESSID TEXT)""")

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients (Station TEXT, First_seen TEXT, Last_seen TEXT, Power INT, 
Packets INT, BSSID TEXT, Probed_ESSID TEXT)""")

with open('dump-01.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        if not row:
            continue

        if row[0] == 'BSSID':
            current_table = 'access_points'

        elif row[0] == 'Station MAC':
            current_table = 'clients'
            # cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO {current_table} VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', row)

        else:
            cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO {current_table} VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', row[:-1])

con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: Hi. What does “not success” look like in this case? Errors? What’s the state of the DB after this runs?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the problem is with the Inserts, because when I run your modified code:

```py
with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    current_table = ""
    for row in reader:
        if not row:
            continue
        elif row[0] == "BSSID":
            current_table = "access_points"
        elif row[0] == "Station MAC":
            current_table = "clients"
        else:
            print(f"{current_table}: {row[:-1]}")
```

on this pared down CSV:

```
BSSID,FOO
64:6D:6C...,foo
AC:37:28...,foo
C4:27:28...,foo
B8:C1:A2...,foo

Station MAC,BAR
BC:2F:3D...,bar
OE:90:E6...,bar
E4:5F:01...,bar
```

I get this correct-looking-to-me output:

```
access_points: ['64:6D:6C...']
access_points: ['AC:37:28...']
access_points: ['C4:27:28...']
access_points: ['B8:C1:A2...']
clients: ['BC:2F:3D...']
clients: ['OE:90:E6...']
clients: ['E4:5F:01...']
```

So, I imagine the problem lies with actually inserting the correct data.  I think debugging will be easier if you separate your process into two steps: first parse the CSV to your liking (verify the data/structure); then try the inserts with a known quantity:

```py
ap_rows = []
client_rows = []
with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    table = []
    for row in reader:
        if not row:
            continue
        elif row[0] == "BSSID":
            table = ap_rows
        elif row[0] == "Station MAC":
            table = client_rows
        else:
            table.append(row[:-1])

print("Access Points:")
pprint.pprint(ap_rows, width=20)
print("Clients:")
pprint.pprint(client_rows, width=20)

# Access Points:
# [['64:6D:6C...'],
#  ['AC:37:28...'],
#  ['C4:27:28...'],
#  ['B8:C1:A2...']]
# Clients:
# [['BC:2F:3D...'],
#  ['OE:90:E6...'],
#  ['E4:5F:01...']]

# Do SQL stuff
...
```